# Timer is not ticking

Tags: c#, timer

Does anyone know why my timer isn't working? Added a timer into my form. The interval is 1000.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Visible = true;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Start();
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer2.Interval == 3000)
    {
        label5.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

After 3 seconds the label is still visible, and the interval is still on 1000. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not changing timer interval in your code, It is set to `1000` and in your Timer Elapsed event you are checking if Interval is `3000`. Your condition will always be false

Answer (score 5):

```
if (timer2.Interval == 3000)
{
    label5.Visible = false;
}
```

Since you state that the interval is 1000, the `if` condition always evaluates as `false`.

A timer fires at regular intervals. Specified by the `Interval` property. You should set the interval to `3000`, and hide the label the first time the timer fires. When that happens you can disable the timer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Visible = true;
    timer2.Interval = 3000;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Visible = false;
    timer2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This helped me out. I will take a further look into it, thanks alot.